# TypeError: $(...).telerik_ReportViewer is not a function Using Jest test in my React Typescript Application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, telerik-reporting

● ReportViewer › renders without crashing

```
TypeError: $(...).telerik_ReportViewer is not a function                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                               
  27 |     // Initialize the Telerik Report Viewer with the props                                                                                              
  28 |     if (this.reportViewerRef) {                                                                                                                         
> 29 |       ($(this.reportViewerRef) as any).telerik_ReportViewer({
     |                                        ^
  30 |         serviceUrl: 'http://localhost/ReportWebAPI/api/reports/',
  31 |         reportSource: reportSource,
  32 |         scale: scale,

  at ReportViewer.telerik_ReportViewer [as componentDidMount] (src/components/Reporting/Reportviewer/ReportViewerComponent.tsx:29:40)
  at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23310:28)
  at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24688:9)
  at commitLayoutEffects_begin (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24674:7)
  at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24612:3)
  at commitRootImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26823:5)
  at commitRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26682:5)
  at finishConcurrentRender (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25981:9)
  at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25809:7)
  at flushActQueue (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2667:24)
  at act (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2582:11)
  at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:46:25
  at renderRoot (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:161:26)
  at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:247:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Reporting/Reportviewer/ReportViewerComponent.test.tsx:32:11)
```

> Trying to Test My ReportViewer.TSX Component using Jest have below is the code But getting above error any lead for the same

```
// Initialize the Telerik Report Viewer with the props
if (this.reportViewerRef) {
  ($(this.reportViewerRef) as any).telerik_ReportViewer({
    serviceUrl: 'http://localhost/ReportWebAPI/api/reports/',
    reportSource: reportSource,
    scale: scale,
    viewMode: viewMode,
    printMode: printMode,
    sendEmail: sendEmail,
  });

}
```